# How can I wrap multiple business transactions under another transaction?

Tags: c#, transactions, repository-pattern, service-layer

In my project, a single service method is a business transaction. For instance, assume I have the following Service/Repository:

```
public interface IDocumentService {

    void CreateDocument(Document doc);
    void AttachFileToDocument(int documentId, string filepath);

}

public class DocumentService 
{
    private readonly IDocumentRepository _repository;

    public DocumentService(IDocumentRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void CreateDocument(Document doc)
    {
        // do some validation
        // ..

        // create entity object....direct mapping, automapper, whatever
        DocEntity entity = new DocEntity()
        entity.Name = doc.Name;
        // etc

        using (var db = new DbEntities())
        {
            _repository.Insert(db, doc);
            _repository.AddSource(db, entity, doc.Sheet.SourceId);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void AttachFileToDocument(int documentId, string filepath)
    {
        using (var context = new DbEntities())
        {
            DocEntity doc = _repository.GetById(context, id);
            // validation etc

            using (var tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // ..
                    // determine filename
                    // copy file
                    // update pointer to file in doc database
                    // ..

                    // save changes
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    tran.Commit();
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are two separate things, so they get their own method. However, **some times** but not all, they would both be required and need to be atomic. I have tried to create a new service method that wraps these in a transaction, but it will not rollback the db create.

How else can I achieve this using the same general design pattern - or is this not a good pattern to follow in this case - one context per business transaction?

Comment: I would just expand on the CreateDocument method. Let it include 0 or more files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make both methods share the same database connection and transaction. How you do that is your choice.

Your code looks like an anti-pattern. You're supposed to use one ObjectContext per unit-of-work where the UOW scope should encompass everything you need to do. Often, the scope is an HTTP request.

If you do that the problem goes away. But you can also solve it any way you like as long as you share the same connection and transaction.

Consider using `TransactionScope` to separate transaction semantics from the rest. Be careful - you still need to share a single connection or else you will promote to distributed transactions.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it would be more appropriate to inject the context into the Service as a class level variable and control the transaction/saving at the application layer (in my case the controller which interacts with the service). I'm not sure what you mean by 'using TransactionScope to separate transaction semantics from the rest', can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can ignore the TransactionScope remarks. They are not important for this question.

Comment: So, transaction should not be considered a part of "business logic"?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. You can use TS to dictate/inject transaction behavior from a higher layer, though. That's very handy.